# Printing a single bibtex entry as enumeration item

Tags: bibtex, formatting, enumerate

I have a bibliography in BibTeX. However I need to report the most important literature I have written thus far. These three entries must be presented in the enumeration environment.

Of course one can simply format these entries properly. However I am looking for a more elegant solution where I only specify the key and the LaTeX compiler formats the entry properly.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick would be to redefine the `thebibliography` environment as the `enumerate`  environment

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\item}
```